# Why ng-class is not applied as per the current state of ui router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-class

My application has two different views (page1 and page2), which has been configured with `ui-router`'s `stateProvider`. I want to apply a css on the body based on what page I am looking at. If I am looking at page1 I want to apply `class1` to the body of the page and `class2` for page2.

To achieve this I am using the `ng-class` directive of the `angularjs`. The value of the `ng-class` directive is being set as per the current state of the `ui-router`.

Here is the example code for it, the problem is that the expression inside the `ng-class` doesn't get evaluated, so my css doesn't get applied.

Can anyone point me what I am doing wrong ?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <style media="screen">

    h2 {
      margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }
    body {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .class1 {
      align-items: flex-start;
    }
    .class2 {
      align-items: center;
    }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="graceApp" ng-class="$state.current.data.bodyClass">

    <div ui-view style="display: flex"></div>

    <script>
    angular
      .module('graceApp', [
        'ui.router'
      ])
      .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
          .state('page1', {
            url: '/page1',
            template: '<h2>This is page1</h2> <h2>Item1</h2> <h2>Item2</h2>',
            data: {
              bodyClass: 'class1'
            }
          })
          .state('page2', {
            url: '/page2',
            template: '<h2>This is page2</h2> <h2>Item1</h2> <h2>Item2</h2>',
            data: {
              bodyClass: 'class2'
            }
          });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/page1');
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $state service is not available in HTML. You just have access in the html to the variables set in the scope so a quick fix would be to set the state in the rootScope then you could access it in the HTML.

```
$rootScope.$state = $state;
```

Comment: where should I write that ?

Comment: in the .run function of your module.
look here:   [Module Loading & Dependencies](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) 

    .run(function ($state,$rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
})

Comment: so after the .config(function () {})
                   .run(function() {});

Comment: This works thanks, but I don't understand the purpose of `run` function, I have to read docs more thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether `$state` service is accessible in HTML like this. Did you consider to create some function in your controller that will return `$state.current.data.bodyClass` and then, you link that function into `ng-class`

```
function getClass() {
    return $state.current.data.bodyClass;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="graceApp" ng-class="getClass()">
```

If you are using controllerAs pattern, make sure you make this function public and use it inside HTML with controller alias.

Comment: Would you please share how did you try this.

Comment: Well, I meant some live demo

Comment: well I don't have such, isn't the code I shared self-explanatory?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access `$state` in html directly, so you need to define another scope variable in controller like

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="graceApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <style media="screen">
    .class1 {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .class2 {
        background-color: green;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController" ng-class="bodyClass">
    <div ui-view></div>
    <script>
    angular.module('graceApp', ['ui.router']).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('page1', {
                url: '/page1',
                template: '<h2>This is page1</h2> <h2>Item1</h2> <h2>Item2</h2>',
                data: {
                    bodyClass: 'class1'
                }
            })
            .state('page2', {
                url: '/page2',
                template: '<h2>This is page2</h2> <h2>Item1</h2> <h2>Item2</h2>',
                data: {
                    bodyClass: 'class2'
                }
            });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/page1');
    });

    angular.module("graceApp").controller("mainController", function($rootScope, $scope) {
        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function(event, current, params) {
            console.log(current.data.bodyClass);
            $scope.bodyClass = current.data.bodyClass;
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am getting `angular.js:14362TypeError: Cannot read property 'bodyClass' of undefined` after adding controller for body.

Comment: moreover when I do `console.log($state);` I can see values under that object but when I do `console.log($state.current);`  the object gets changed and I can't see values there. this looks strange.

Comment: @bruce_wayne I've updated my answer, and provided the full solution